# How do I prevent natd from accessing a specific external address?

Tags: security, mac-osx, permissions, http, nat

I'm using Little Snitch, and it's telling me natd is accessing tonix.sytes.net (a torrent tracker) every second or so. I have been unable to backtrace which program is making the call, and if I "block" access to tonix.sytes.net for natd or all programs via Little Snitch preferences, nothing happens and the connections continue.

I've searched all my plist files in /etc/ and /SystemConfiguration/ but I haven't found tonix.sytes.net at all. I also can't get an IP Address from tonix.sytes.net, but I got one from tonix.sytes.net:6969, which was 208.68.143.50. I also couldn't find this in any plist.

What should I do? How can I stop these connections and/or trace the program that is making the requests?

Update:

No, I'm not using / have never used Internet Sharing.

After repeatedly blocking tonix.sytes.net with little snitch and natd, it has stopped happening. In fact all traffic from natd is now not appearing in Little Snitch, which is bothersome.

I checked for Mac Defender and Mac Guard (trojans disguised as anti-virus programs), but I don't have either installed. The only one I have is Norton and MacScan, which are legit.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Internet Sharing?  If so, it's likely a program on some other computer that's using your shared internet connection, and just being translated by natd.